# MCP3008 Reading Values without Ground

Tags: power-supply, sensor

I’ve been building a spectrophotometer the last few months and am confused by the ADC’s behavior regarding grounding. While everything appears to be working properly, including the ADC output, I have noticed that the ADC still outputs values, proportional to the voltage, when the circuit isn’t grounded. Depending on the circuit and voltage being measured, the ungrounded ADC varies by 0-33% compared to grounded ADC.

To investigate, I started looking for a ground source and determined it be the RPI’s clock pin. Whenever I connect the ADC’s clock to the RPI clock pin, the circuit is powered—-to some extent. LEDs will light up to nearly full brightness, op amp starts amplifying signals and the ADC outputs values that correspond to the input with varying deviation from grounded circuit.

My questions are:

1. Is the clock pin on the RPI tied to ground when not pulled high? Or is my RPI clock pin burned out?
2. Is the MCP3008 clock pin internally tied to one of the ground pins—-AGND or DGND?
3. What would be the best way to isolate this grounding effect on my board? I don’t want the entire board receiving power unless I have my board’s negative pin connected to ground.
   [here’s my circuit diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgqGo.jpg)

Comment: Which pin is the "RPI clock pin"? I wouldn't know that this is exposed somewhere.

Comment: You really need to show the connections.

Comment: A schematic is really needed here. Please also clarify what you mean when you say "the circuit isn't grounded"...that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I’ve added a circuit diagram so y’all can better understand my situation. All 5V supplies are coming from the same rail.

Comment: @PMF I’m using the SPI clock pin (SCLK, pin23)

Comment: I can see no wire connecting a Pi ground to the ADC ground.

Comment: It is pretty normal that some of these low-power chips (such as the MCP3008) work "somehow" when they get power over clock lines or even over their measurement inputs. But they will not work reliably that way.

Comment: @joan The 5V and ground on the board are powered by the pi.

Comment: @PMF Huh, that’s interesting. Ultimately, it doesn’t concern me much since my measurements are pretty accurate when grounded. I was just curious why it was happening and wanted to know if it was a result of a broken component on the chip or pi. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The reason for what PMF said are the ADC's ESD protection diodes. They raise the ADC's Vcc to some extend and will conduct all the current the adc sinks. But they are not meant to conduct continuous current and the adc will eventually fail. You should not operate the adc without proper ground connection and without providing Vcc.